# HP Split X2 - Clean install of Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, uefi, secure-boot

I would like to install a clean install of Windows 8 Enterprise on my HP Split X2 (it has the new UEFI/Secure Boot). Thus far all of my attempts have been unsuccessful... I've tried Secure  Boot enabled and disabled, legacy mode enabled and disabled... I've tried booting from a DVD, from a USB parted GPT, MBR, etc. configured for secure boot, and not. I need advice.. I'm at my witts end and about to return the computer even though I really like it.

EDIT: When booting the DVD in Legacy Mode, install will boot however the SSD is inaccessible due to a "missing sata driver". When I try to install said driver, it says no new device drivers were found.

Comment: which issues do you have during setup? Provide more details otherwise we close the topic.

Comment: Rather snippy response... kindness would be appreciated. See edit.

Comment: what happens when you boot in UEFI mode?

Comment: Besides that one setting in which the install will actually boot, I get the error the error that it's not bootable.

Comment: what is not bootable? the DVD?

Comment: Anything I use to boot it besides the installed OS on the SSD. I've tried DVDs, and USBs formatted in every way they have suggested on the forums for installing UEFI. The USBs return "Selected Boot image did not authenticate. Press <enter> to continue." The DVDs just don't show up in the boot menu.

Comment: "Selected Boot image did not authenticate" this sounds like Secure Boot issue. Have you modified the Enterprise Image?

Comment: I have not. The only thing I have done was the steps outlined here: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/15458-uefi-bootable-usb-flash-drive-create-windows.html

Comment: download the Win8 Enterprise ISO again. Your ISO may be damaged.

Comment: Alright. I'll let you know what happens. I'll do a checksum against the university's website too to check the iso.

Comment: Must have been a bad copy. I prepared a USB Drive with the freshly downloaded iso and my bootcamp assistant (easiest way to make a bootable USB) and it UEFI booted quite easily. I do apologize, as this is my first experience with UEFI and I thought I was doing something stupid/wrong that was an easy fix or that something was wrong that I could not fix. Thanks for your help!

Comment: nice to hear. I posted my comment about the ISO as answer so that you can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

ok, issues like "Selected Boot image did not authenticate" and "missing sata driver" are often caused by corrupted ISOs. Download the Windows 8 Enterprise ISO again and make sure the hash is fine.